# How do I approach these number theory questions?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that there are infinitely many $ a \in  Z$ such that

- $ 5n + a$ is not a prime for all $n \in  N $
- $n^2 + a$ is not a prime for all $n \in  N $

These questions seem to be simple but I do not know how to approach these questions...

I would appreciate any help

Comment: By contraposition i guess

Comment: in the second case, is $a$ fixed or could be $a(n)$?

Answer (score 1):

The idea for the first one is to pick $a$ so that $5n+a$ is always divisible by some small prime, hence cannot be prime itself (with at most one exception if it turns out to be equal to the small prime). How can $a$ be chosen so that $5n+a$ is always divisible by $5$, regardless of what $n$ is?

For the second question, think about differences of squares, and how they can be factored.

Answer (score 0):

Take $a=5k$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then for all these infinitely many $a$'s we have that $5\mid (5n+a)=5(n+k)$ is not prime, with $k+n\neq 1$. Hence $5n+a$ is not prime for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

Pick even n. Then 5*n will be even and for all even 'a', 5*n + a will not be prime, since it is even.
Same logic for second question too.